# MySQL 2 queries combine into 1 query

Tags: mysql

So I have to query a DB table based on a certain type and would like to do it in 1 query only. Below are the queries I would like to combine:

1. SELECT usr_id, SUM(coins) AS coinppv FROM `coin_tbl` WHERE coin_type = 1 GROUP BY usr_id
2. SELECT usr_id, SUM(coins) AS coinmly FROM `coin_tbl` WHERE coin_type = 3 GROUP BY usr_id

Then I would also like to get the sum of coinppv and coinmly then finally GROUP BY usr_id.

I have tried doing something like the ff. but I don't get the result I wanted:
(NOTE: this example did not include summing up coinppv and coinmly)

```
SELECT usr_id,
(SELECT SUM(coins) FROM `coin_tbl` WHERE coin_type = 1) AS coinppv,
(SELECT SUM(coins) FROM `coin_tbl` WHERE coin_type = 3) AS coinmly
FROM `coin_tbl` GROUP BY usr_id
```

I also looked into JOINing but I also didn't get the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT usr_id,
       SUM(IF(coin_type = 1,coins,0)) AS coinppv,
       SUM(IF(coin_type = 3,coins,0)) AS coinmly, 
       SUM(coins) AS total
FROM `coin_tbl` 
WHERE coin_type IN (1,3)
GROUP BY usr_id
```

total is sum of types 1 and 3, remove where if you need total of all

Comment: Great! This is the solution to my problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

Use `In`

```
SELECT usr_id, SUM(coins) 
AS coinppv 
FROM coin_tbl
WHERE coin_type 
IN( 1,3) 
GROUP BY usr_id
```

Comment: no. I'd like to get the sum of coinppv via cointype = 1 and coinmly via cointype 3. A user can have coins coming from both type 1 and type 3 so the solution above did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Aadrinmusic ohh..sorry for being late with the reply(stuck at  a discussion), DonCallisto updated the answer in the mean time ..let me know if it was what ur looking for ..otherwise happy to assist you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT usr_id, coin_type, SUM(coins)
FROM coin_tbl 
WHERE coin_type = 1 OR coin_type = 3 
GROUP BY usr_id, coin_type
```

See it in action on **[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03f22/1)**

[Swapnesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639406/swapnesh) answer (once he will edit it) is better as it use `IN` clause that is more readable if you have to control `coin_type` against "many" different type (say five or six), but if only two `coin_type` are involved, there isn't much difference

Comment: please see my comment from swapnesh

Comment: only usr_id and coinppv are in the results, coinmly was missing so it's not it. thanks

Comment: @Aadrinmusic: no, there are coinmly also (type=3) take a depth look yo my answer and fiddle; I've only aliased them under same name, but data is there

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in one row per user id, with both values then something like this should do it

```
SELECT usr_id, SUM(if(coin_type = 1, coins, 0)) AS coinppv, SUM(if(coin_type = 3, coins, 0)) AS coinmly
FROM coin_tbl 
GROUP BY usr_id
```

If you wanted to do it as a JOIN and assuming you have a table of users you could use something like the following

```
SELECT usr_id, IFNULL(Sub1.coinppv, 0), IFNULL(Sub2.coinmly, 0)
FROM user_table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT usr_id, SUM(coins) AS coinppv FROM `coin_tbl` WHERE coin_type = 1 GROUP BY usr_id) Sub1 ON coin_tbl.usr_id = Sub1.usr_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT usr_id, SUM(coins) AS coinmly FROM `coin_tbl` WHERE coin_type = 3 GROUP BY usr_id) Sub2 ON coin_tbl.usr_id = Sub2.usr_id
```